# Constructor error when Arguments in it isn't declared as const

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

```
class Point2d
{
public:
    Point2d();
    Point2d(int X, int Y);
    ~Point2d();
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
};

class Creature
{
private:
    Point2d& m_yer;
    const std::string& m_Name;
public:
    Creature() = delete;
    Creature(const std::string& name, Point2d& location) : m_Name(name), m_yer(location) {}
    void Creature_Move(int x, int y);
    ~Creature();
};

int main()
{
    std::string name = "Monke";
    Point2d abc{ 25,30 };
    Creature canavva(name, abc);
   //Creature canavv(name, Point2d{ 40,50 }); //Gives error
    return 0;
}
```

But when I put `const` in the argument `Creature(const std::string& name, const Point2d& location)` and `const Point2d& m_yer;` then
`Creature canavv(name, Point2d{ 40,50 })` doesn't give error.

How can I initiliaze Poin2d without `const` keyword because I'm changing values inside it.

Comment: Modifying a temporary in this fashion is considered an error by the language.

Comment: Why does `Creature` have a reference to a `Point2d` instead of its own value?

Comment: To avoid copy constructor

Comment: Write valid code first, care to optimize when needed.

Comment: @BarisSapa That is not a good idea, copying Point2D is trivial. As a reference, you need to make sure it remains valid as long as the Creature object needs to use it.

Comment: Copy constructor? You understand that the copy constructor consists of copying 2 ints, right? That's basically nothing. Use a reference when you need a reference. Making it a value will solve your problem.

Comment: @BarisSapa *To avoid copy constructor* -- You will not be able to outsmart or beat an optimizing compiler by writing such code.  Code that tries to do this ultimately fails at making the code faster, and in many cases, makes the code slower.

Comment: If you are really determined to do the bad thing, you can do it by `Creature canavv(name, const_cast<Point2d&>(static_cast<const Point2d&>(Point2d{40, 50})));`

Comment: @Eljay How does this work? as far as I understand, you converted it to const and converted it back.